# How to click on the button with text as Find What County I'm In through Selenium and Python in Jupyter

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jupyter-notebook, webdriverwait

Here is html of the button that I wanna click on it:
I think I should grab the visible one.(I guess)

```
 <form id="search-form">
                  <div class="input-group hidden-xs">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="getUserExactLocation();scrollToMap();">Find What County I'm In</button>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter address here" id="address">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="findAddress();scrollToMap();">Find County for Address</button>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group visible-xs">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter address here" id="address-xs">
                    <button class="btn btn-default xs-btn" type="button" onclick="findAddress();scrollToMap();">Find County for Address</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default xs-btn" type="button" onclick="getUserExactLocation();scrollToMap();">Find What County I'm In</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

I can put the data to the search area. However, I can not submit my button to get return data:
I have this code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from collections import namedtuple

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-county-am-i-in.php")
mainsoup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml') 

listB=[]
listC= ['1209 SE 2nd Ave,Grand Rapids,MN,55744', '415 9th Avenue,Granite Falls,MN,56241', '22 East 6th St,Mantorville,MN,55955']

for query in listC:
    address= driver.find_element_by_id("address")
    address.send_keys(query)
    submitButton=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[onclick*='getUserExactLocation();scrollToMap();']").click()
    county_result= driver.find_element_by_id('display_county')
    listB = listB + [county_result.text]
print(listB)
```

For submitButton, I also try:

```
submitButton= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btnbtn-defaultxs-btn').click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default xs-btn'][@type='button'][contains(., 'input-group visible-xs')]").click()
```

result should like this:

```
["Yellow Medicine County", "Yellow Medicine County", "Dodge County"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. You need to induce *WebDriverwait* before entering the *locations* within the *Enter address here* field and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-county-am-i-in.php")
  listB = []
  listC = ['1209 SE 2nd Ave,Grand Rapids,MN,55744', '415 9th Avenue,Granite Falls,MN,56241', '22 East 6th St,Mantorville,MN,55955']
  for query in listC:
      address = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control#address")))
      address.clear()
      address.send_keys(query)
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default' and starts-with(@onclick, 'getUserExactLocation')]").click()
      # In the next line instead of the element with text as "County" you need to handle the "::before" / "::after" Pseudo Element
      county_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row county-result']")))
      listB.append(county_result.text)
  print(listB)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['County', 'County', 'County']
  ```

Comment: I still got same county for all addresses. ['County\nHennepin County', 'County\nHennepin County', 'County\nHennepin County']

Comment: @ThaoN See the commented line within the code block where I have mentioned you have to handle the pseudo element which is not a part of your problem.

Comment: Thank you DebanjanB. I use you your wait func with QHarr suggestion. It works perfectly.

Comment: could you explain me more abour ""::before" / "::after" Pseudo Element ? @DebanjanB

Comment: Handling `"::before" / "::after" Pseudo Element` is not a part of this question and you may have to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: Handling `"::before" / "::after" Pseudo Element` is not a part of this question and you may have to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a more efficient xhr post request instead and parse the json response.

```
import requests 
url = 'https://www.mapdevelopers.com/data.php?operation=geocode'
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'}

listB=[]
listC= ['1209 SE 2nd Ave,Grand Rapids,MN,55744', '415 9th Avenue,Granite Falls,MN,56241'] #, '22 East 6th St,Mantorville,MN,55955']

for query in listC:
    body = {'address' : query}
    res = requests.post(url, data = body).json()
    listB.append(res['data']['county'])
print(listB)
```

Comment: It missed some data since it does not wait untill the website load the result. I use WebDriverWait from @DebanjanB below.

Comment: @QHarr Can you please point me towards some documentation on `xhr` stuff?

Comment: @DebanjanB https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest  though the implementation here would be the requests documentation.

Comment: @QHarr The link to the documentation was very helpful. Would you like to point me towards the documentation of `xhr` implementation through requests  as well?

Comment: @DebanjanB I don't know where the real detail of the implementation is. I guess in the source code. You can review the methods/properties http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the useful links

Answer (score 0):

By using a HTTP GET request. I believe the request for geocode now expects 2 more required params "lid" and "lcode" (not sure what thay are), those are being captured by parsing the response on page load, another http get request to gecocode api will all required params, gives the expected json data.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

url = "https://www.mapdevelopers.com/what-is-my-address.php"
resource = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
contents = resource.read().decode('utf-8')
lid = contents.split("var lid = \"")[1].split("\"")[0]
lcode = contents.split("var lcode = \"")[1].split("\"")[0]
# pass address here
address = urllib.parse.quote_plus("New Delhi")
print("Getting location details for - ", address)
url = "https://www.mapdevelopers.com/data.php?operation=geocode&address="+address+"&lcode="+lcode+"&lid="+lid
resource = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
JSON_object = json.loads(resource.read().decode('utf-8'))
print(JSON_object)
```